# How to set default value checked in a checkbox from database using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

While editing the record the data comes in their respective fields for editing, but the checkbox is not checked if its value is `1`.

It should be in checked state if it has `1` and not checked if it has `0` as the datatype of the field is `tinyint`. I am retrieving the data from JSON array via PHP. I am trying to get value by `ng-checked="{{rec.isSpecial}}"` but it is not working.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
    <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{rec.isSpecial}}" ng-model="rec.isSpecial">
        <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Special
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my JS

```
$scope.rec = $resource('api/AdminArea/category/edit/:id', {
  id: id
}).get(function(data) {
  $scope.rec = data;
});
```

Comment: check without {{}} for ng-check

Comment: thanx for reply let me check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your data returns numbers and not true or false values you could do like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="rec.isSpecial==1" ng-model="rec.isSpecial">
          <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Special
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/54r6tjeg/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ng-checked` at all, `ng-model` is enough for it to work. If your `rec.isSpecial` is set to `1` for it to be checked then just your `input` like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="rec.isSpecial" ng-value="1" />
```

and the Angular will automatically check that checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `ng-checked={{ ... }}` expects a `true` or `false` statement.
If you would set `rec.isSpecial = true`, in your Angular controller, your code should work!

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]); 
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.isSpecial =true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" ng-app ="MyApp" ng-controller="myController">
                              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                 <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                                    <label>
                       <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{isSpecial}}" ng-model="isSpecial">
                                       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Special
                                      </label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
```

Comment: you need to assign or set in controller  $scope.isSpecial =true; for rec you need set value

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the directive `ng-checked` if you are using `ng-model` in the tag input.

Since it is a checkbox, the model will be a boolean, so you need to make a cast. This example will work

HTML

```
<div data-ng-app="app">

  <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
    Check
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="isSpecial">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function mainController($scope){

  $scope.check = 0;
  $scope.isSpecial = ($scope.check === 1) ? true : false;

}
```